# How to work with LiveData on RecyclerView?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

**The problem is this: I press the button to delete an item in the list and it is deleted. But when I rotate the screen, the list is reloaded. The list does not save the data.

LiveData does not see changes.How to pass a new list with the removed element through it ? I spent 10 hours solving this problem (**

**Adapter**

```
class ItemAdapter(var context: Context, private var arrayList: MutableList<NumberModel>):RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemHolder{

    val itemHolder = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
        R.layout.grid_layout_list_item,
        parent,
        false
    )
    return ItemHolder(itemHolder)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemHolder, position: Int) {
    var positionOfNumber:NumberModel = arrayList.get(position)
    holder.textOfNumber.text = positionOfNumber.numberOfElement
   holder.button.setOnClickListener {
       var positionForDelete = holder.adapterPosition
       arrayList.removeAt(positionForDelete)
       notifyItemRemoved(positionForDelete)
       notifyItemRangeChanged(positionForDelete,arrayList.size)
   }
}
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return arrayList.size
}

class ItemHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var textOfNumber = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.numberTextView)
    var button:Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonClick)
}
```

}

**MainActivity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val list = mutableListOf<NumberModel>()
    adapter = ItemAdapter(this,list)
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewList)
    gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(applicationContext,2,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
    recyclerView?.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
    recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView?.adapter = adapter

    val model= ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
    model.getListElements().observe(this, Observer {elementsSnapshot ->
        // Received elements from ViewModel
        list.clear()
        // Take new data from snapshot
        list.addAll(elementsSnapshot)
        adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class MainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {
private val elementsList: MutableLiveData<MutableList<NumberModel>>

init {
    elementsList = MutableLiveData()
    elementsList.value = setElements()
}
fun getListElements() : LiveData<MutableList<NumberModel>>{
   return elementsList
}

private fun setElements() : MutableList<NumberModel> {
    val itemArrayList:MutableList<NumberModel> = ArrayList()
    itemArrayList.add(NumberModel("1"))
    itemArrayList.add(NumberModel("2"))
    itemArrayList.add(NumberModel("3"))
    itemArrayList.add(NumberModel("4"))
    itemArrayList.add(NumberModel("5"))
    return itemArrayList
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Mutating object returned from your ViewModel is rarely a good idea. Reacting to event (such as user clicking your delete button) should be done in ViewModel. This is consistent with reactive UI style (data goes down, events go up) and will allow you to seperate your logic (ViewModel) from UI details (Activity, Adapter).

Your ViewModel could expose two elements:

```kotlin
class MyViewModel {
    private val localElements = MutableLiveData<List<...>>()

    val elements: LiveData<List<...>> 
        get() = localElements

    fun onElementClicked(index: Int) { 
        // get current value of localElements, make a copy of it with removed value at [index] and publish it to localElements
    }
}
```

Then, you can expose `setElements` method in your Adapter and just call it in response to `viewModel.elements` changes. You can pass instance of ViewModel to your Adapter and call `onElementClicked` when you detect the click.

This way, you can think of your Activity and Adapter as basically "stateless". When configuration changes, the valid state will be preserved in your ViewModel.

PS. Android documentation recommends retrieving your ViewModel instance during construction of your Activity/Fragment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide?authuser=1#build-ui

Comment: I tried to do like this, but nothing worked. I Add this in adapter
var example:MainActivityViewModel = MainActivityViewModel() exp.updateElements(arrayList.size)
And add this in ViewModel
fun updateElements(item: Int) {

itemArrayList.size == item

}

Comment: How do I pass a new list from the adapter ? With object LiveData ?

Comment: You should pass ViewModel to Adapter from your Activity, not create a new instance of it. Why would you want to pass list from Adapter to ViewModel? Remember: *data* (such as list) go *down* (ViewModel -> Adapter via LiveData) and *events* (such as "user clicked sth") go *up* (Adapter -> ViewModel via method call)

Comment: I tried to follow your advice, but still something went wrong, of course I am to blame.
I will be very very grateful if you look at the code and tell me what the problem is.Pls
https://github.com/MisterPendragon/AvitoProject

Comment: You're still trying to delete item in onClick callback. Don't do this, just call your ViewModel method and let it take care of updating your data